# Pidgin Repository / Packages for Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: package-management, pidgin

I enjoy using Pidgin on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, but recently my XMPP with Google Apps stopped working (Google claims my sign in was from *"an app that doesn't meet modern security standards"*).

Before trying the latest Google Hangouts plugin, I'd like to get the latest version of Pidgin.

There don't seem to be any up-to-date packages/repositories out there. Would anyone be interested in providing one? I'm willing to bounty this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even the latest Pidgin does not work with Google's new security standards, which require you to login to a Google app authentication portal from inside the app.

I do not believe there is a solution to fix this at this time.

Comment: Thank you. There is a new plugin out there that someone coded up for Google Hangouts. https://bitbucket.org/EionRobb/purple-hangouts/ I might just try to wrap that one into this older version I have here in Ubuntu. Meanwhile just using Google's linux-based hangouts but it is inferior.